# SharePoint 2019 - on premise - User Profile synchronization connection

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, 2019, synchronization, userprofile-sync

I need to make a new Synchronization Connection for user profile sync.
Do I need to delete the old Synchronization connection before I create an new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple connections per UPSA. Now, if you're doing this to troubleshoot an issue and are attempting to reconnect to an existing Active Directory forest, you should ask for specific help surrounding a problematic connection.

Comment: I have a string which imports but does not update from AD even when the users are disabled and removed from the synced OU. I was hoping to replicate the string to see if this would and could adjust the true numbers of this OU. I can see I cannot do this - only one string per forest. Any advice

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Trevor Seward.

You can create one, two or multiple sync connections per UPA. However, you should only have a single sync connection per Active Directory forest.

Comment: Ok - well my problem is with the existing string and forest